# надо изменить значение в mysql таблице с помощью ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible, ansible-playbook

Хочу изменить все значения в мускульной таблице на удаленных серверах, ансибл запускаю с локалки, столкнулся с проблемой: ниже пример плейбука и ошибка, буду благодарен за любую помощь

```
- hosts: nodes
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: mysqlUpdate
      community.mysql.mysql_query:
       query:
       - update table_name set original = 'user_password' where user_name = 'name'
#      ignore_errors: yes
```

вот ошибка:
`fatal: [server_ip]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1698, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'\")"}`

догадываюсь, что просто юзер нейм и пароль можно указать в самом плейбуке, но не нашел, как оно должно выглядеть.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение, может кому-то будет полезно:

```
- hosts: hosts
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: mysqlUpdate
      community.mysql.mysql_query:
       login_user: login
       login_password: password
       query:
       - update Users set password = 'password' where name = 'name'
#      ignore_errors: yes
```